# Django with Celery: Getting the status from an undergoing task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task, djcelery

I am currently testing Django with Celery.

A periodic task is setup with a crontab to run the following task add:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import task
import time

@task
def add(x, y):
    print "Start : %s" % time.ctime()
    time.sleep(120)
    print "End : %s" % time.ctime()
    return x + y
```

The model:

```
from django.db import models
from djcelery.models import CrontabSchedule
from djcelery.models import TaskState

class Manager(models.Model):
    cron = models.ForeignKey(CrontabSchedule)

    def app_status(self):
        return self.cron.schedule.app.tasks

    app_status.admin_order_field = 'app status'
```

Now I would like to be able to access the state of the current or last task. With Django shell, I can obtain the following:

```
>>> import django
>>> from extractionapp.models import Manager
>>> Manager.objects.all()[0].app_status()
{'celery.chain': <@task: celery.chain of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.chord': <@task: celery.chord of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'proj.celery.debug_task': <@task: proj.celery.debug_task of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.chunks': <@task: celery.chunks of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.chord_unlock': <@task: celery.chord_unlock of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.group': <@task: celery.group of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.backend_cleanup': <@task: celery.backend_cleanup of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.map': <@task: celery.map of proj:0x1022f1a90>, 'celery.starmap': <@task: celery.starmap of proj:0x1022f1a90>}
```

However, I cannot access the add task from this, neither its state.
Calling the task by its name does not work either:

> > > Manager.objects.all()[0].app_status()['extractionapp.tasks.add']
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > >           File "/Users/antoinebrunel/seo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/registry.py", line 26, in **missing**
> > >           raise self.NotRegistered(key)
> > >           NotRegistered: 'extractionapp.tasks.add'

So how can I access the state of the current task assigned to the cron? I can see it from the admin through Home › Djcelery › Tasks, but how can I get that from the code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Django shell:

```
>>> from celery import Celery
>>> app = Celery('proj')
>>> i = app.control.inspect()
>>> i.active()
{u'celery@HeyHeyHey': [{u'args': u'[2, 2]', u'time_start': 448519.58944676, u'name': u'extractionapp.tasks.add', u'delivery_info': {u'priority': None, u'redelivered': False, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'exchange': u'celery'}, u'hostname': u'celery@HeyHeyHey', u'acknowledged': True, u'kwargs': u'{}', u'id': u'05fa4347-a222-45f3-9ee0-f3c261a21a24', u'worker_pid': 23999}]}
```

Source: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#dump-of-currently-executing-tasks